# execvp() creating a small unix shell based program

Tags: c, shell, unix

I have made a small program that forks and executes another program. Basically it's supposed to work just like unix shell.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t cpid;
    char *shell[5];
    shell[0]=argv[1];
    shell[1]=argv[2];
    shell[2]=argv[3];
    shell[4]=NULL;

    if(argc!=4){
        printf("Program expects 4 arguments");
    } else{
        cpid=fork();
        if(cpid==0){
            execvp("/bin/sh",shell);
        }//end child process
        if (cpid != wait(NULL)) {                          /* parent code */
            printf("Parent failed to wait");
            return 1;
        }
    }//end else

}//end main
```

However, when I give the command

```
$ ./shell simple sml_prog1 A
```

it says `sml_prog1 not found` about 15 or 20 times.

The shell is supposed to run `simple` which takes `sml_prog1 A` as arguments.

The program does work on its own with the same arguments.

I changed the permissions of `sml_prog1` to `read/write/executable`. Moreover `sml_prog1` is a `.txt` file that contains data that the program `simple` uses

Comment: the code is checking `argc` too late.  so the reading of argv[x] could be accessing the 'unknown' this is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: 1) check the argc count first.  2) make the shell[] be argc+1 in size to have room for a trailing NULL entry.  3) use: execvp( shell[0], shell );

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is how you're calling `execvp`.  You don't want to execute `/bin/sh`, you want to execute the program the user passed in, i.e. `argv[1]`.

Change the call to this, and add the following error checking:

```
execvp(shell[0],shell);
perror("exec failed");    // This line never gets called unless execvp fails
exit(1);                  // end the child process
```

Also, you never set `shell[3]` to anything.  You probably want to set this to NULL instead of `shell[4]`:

```
shell[0]=argv[1];
shell[1]=argv[2];
shell[2]=argv[3];
shell[3]=NULL;
```

Comment: This solved the 'sml_prog1 not found issue' but now its not executing or doing anything. It just keeps on taking commands after typing ./shell simple sml_prog1 A

Comment: Its giving me information about the users and their permissions

Comment: Am I suppose to include any specific header file for `exit(1)`; to work? It says `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’` At the moment I am only inlcuding `stdio` `unistd.h` and `sys/types.h`

Comment: @AliRehman  For `exit()` you need `stdlib.h`.  Is the command above giving a directory listing?  What does the output look like?

Comment: something like this `total 40
drwxrwxrwt 2 lightdm lightdm 4096 Oct  8 04:36 at-spi2
drwx------ 2 ali     ali     4096 Oct  8 04:36 keyring-nPZgUz
drwx------ 2 ali     ali     4096 Oct  8 04:36 pulse-1umMHHnYzsw3
drwx------ 2 lightdm lightdm 4096 Oct  8 04:37 pulse-2L9K88eMlGn7
drwx------ 2 root    root    4096 Oct  8 04:35 pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n
drwx------ 2 ali     ali     4096 Oct  8 04:36 ssh-ZbTIeeCL2085
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lightdm lightdm    0 Oct  8 04:36 unity_support_test.0
drwx------ 2 ali     ali     4096 Oct  8 04:36 vmware-ali
drwxrwxrwt 2 root    root    4096 Oct  8 04:35 VMwareDnD
`

Comment: @AliRehman That's a directory listing, specifically the output of `ls -l /tmp`.  So it looks like it's working.  Calling your program should work in a similar way.

Comment: `execvp()` is failing, its running `perror("exec failed");`

Comment: @AliRehman Is that all it says?  It should be something like `exec failed: (more descriptive message)`.

Comment: Yes, thats all it says. The solution posted by @old_mountain is working though.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible example of using `execvp()` I can think of is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ++argv;
    if (*argv)
        execvp(*argv, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with:

cc -Wextra -Wall some.c -o some

And run it like:

```
./some ls -la
```

Or to display that all the arguments are getting passed to `execvp()` more clearly:

```
./some ls -la -R /etc
```

To demonstrate it put to use with your exact scenario of invoking a shell compare the output of these two commands (be warned this it is pretty redundant to use /bin/sh directly when one is already using execvp()):

```
./some bash -c 'type history'

./some sh -c 'type history'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute your program through `/bin/sh`, not directly, you must do it differently.

You must pass the program somehow this way:

```
char * shell[4];
shell[0] = "sh";
shell[1] = "-c";
shell[2] = "./simple sml_prog1 A";
shell[3] = NULL;
```

See ? with `-c` option, and the full program

So something like this should do the job for you:

```
char * shell[4];
shell[0] = "sh";
shell[1] = "-c";
char prog[100]; // be careful with this number
snprintf (prog, 100, "./%s %s %s",argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
shell[2] = prog;
shell[3] = NULL;
```